# How to build two different EAR in maven for with same java files in JAVA 6 and JAVA 11 with different jars for both java version?

Tags: java, maven, ear

My project is currently in ant and we want to migrate to maven.
We have to support both java 6 and java 11 build for different servers (Our codebase is compatible with java 6 and above).
Java 6 is using old jar files while Java 11 has new jar files.
We want to compile project with both java 6 and 11 with their own set of jars. (Final build as two different EAR)
Is it possible to achieve this in maven, if yes then how?

Edit: To make myself clear, I do not have code which needs java 7 and above to compile. My codebase if fully compatible with java 6 and above. I just need to compile it with java 11 with newer dependencies to run it on newer version of server while supporting java 6 for old server, Thus one EAR with java 6 and another with java 11. We will be eventually moving to only support java 11 when all of our customer moves to new server.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a multi-module project that contains two modules for the two EARs, and additionally modules for the JARs you want to build.

Then you can set the Java version to 6 in one EAR and to 11 in the other one.

Comment: It is not enough to set the version of the EARs. Instead two fully separate compile runs are necessary. It might happen, that Java 11 compiles/ auto-creates modules-info.java which could break class loading when the Java 6 EAR contains it. The question also outlines different libraries, too. So this would require a sophisticated setup. I'd fully separate both code bases. Stay on the safe side of dependency hell.

Comment: @motzmann If you have two modules in a multi-module project, these are automatically compiled separately. And they can have different dependencies as well. Sorry, motzmann, I did not understand yet what you mean.

Comment: @motzmann Can Java 11 auto-create modules-info.java?

Comment: JDK9+ does not create modules-info automatically only if you create it manually ... apart from that I doubt that you get it working based on libraries but that is a different thing...

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, it does not auto create one. But for example my IDE suggests this and pre-fills some of the require-lines. Since I don't know anything about pom.xml/ environment in charge, I assume the worst case: it suddenly came to life, compiled fine and broke everything in production.

Comment: @JFabianMeier I'm aware of the possibilities. All of my projects are multi-module ones to bind different aspects like static code analysis resources in one module or wrap the application in a separate sub-module instead of stuffing it all in one. But I also use [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) and for example different groupId or artifactId – depending on the required outcome – to set pre-JDK8 code apart from JDK 9/11 (preferrably 11). Copied this from Jackson and other libraries. That is why I assume two nearly independent classpaths.

Comment: @motzmann I would probably only bring in worst case scenarios if hinted relevant by the question.   In this case I would consider this as two different deployment platforms, and create a build module for each.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need different compilers. There is a limitation in backwards compatibility. As far as I remember Oracle JDK supports current minus two major release. Thus JDK 11 javac can compile JDK 8 incl. The first snippet thus – I assume – is something like:

```
<properties>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

This setting can only occur once per (simple) pom.xml as it will affect `maven-compiler-plugin` to set source and target. Again I assume you have a source directory with JDK 6 code and another source directory with JDK 11 code. And your goal is to have all the JDK 6 sources in a compatible way bound to one EAR. At the same time your JDK 11 sources end up in a different EAR and must resemble JDK 11 bytecode.

It is something totally different to have JDK 11 source compiled for a JDK 8 target – still incompatible with a JDK 6 VM. I also assume it is not wanted and also not easy to turn your JDK 11 sources into JDK 6 bytecode through compiler only.

Next I assume you have at least one shared element in classpath for both EARs. It can be your own API JAR or an an external library. Such a dependency would end up in `dependencyManagement` of the so called parent pom. This is the same pom that contains all module definitions.

Third you'll need to define a groupId and various artifactIds. I strongly urge you to express the JDK affinity at least in the artifactId. Then you can express dependencies based on JDK affinity. A skeleton (parent) pom.xml might look like this:

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-cross-release</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <modules>
    <module>sample-cross-release-api</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-source6</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-source11</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-war6</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-war11</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-ear6</module>
    <module>sample-cross-release-ear11</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency><!-- necessary for 6 and 11 source/ WAR/ EAR -->
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-cross-release-api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      <dependency>
      <dependency><!-- only 6 is shown, 11 looks the similar -->
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-cross-release-sources6</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      <dependency>
      <dependency><!-- only 6 is shown, 11 looks the similar -->
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-cross-release-war6</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      <dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I omit the source and WAR-part. But it has a `dependency` on `sample-cross-release-sources6` and the -api, too. The EAR's pom.xml would look like this:

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-cross-release-ear11</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-cross-release</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency><!-- does not need version, determined by parent -->
      <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample-cross-release-api</artifactId>
    <dependency>

    <dependency><!-- does not need version, determined by parent -->
      <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample-cross-release-war6</artifactId>
    <dependency>

    <!-- other dependencies, like logging, persistence... -->
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compile.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the project structure will look like this in the file system:

```
|
+-- pom.xml (parent)
+-- sample-cross-release-api
|    +-- pom.xml
|    +-- src/main/java
|    +-- src/main/resources
|    ...
...
+-- sample-cross-release-ear11
     +-- pom.xml
     ...
```

Finally I urge you to have totally separate JDK 6 and JDK 11 code bases/ projects/ pom.xml-s. Do not merge them with a parent pom. You will end up in dependency hell as soon as you try to setup (Maven-) profiles supporting release plugins for different JDKs/ toolchains. It might work for simple cases. It will break as soon as you bring in static code analysis, surefire/ failsafe and presumably WAR- and EAR-creation. (I assume a JDK 6 EAR is built with a matching JEE dependency which differs from the JEE for JDK 11. This in turn forces the use of compatible Maven plugins – different per JDK.)

And you never know: there will be an application server running on JDK 11 that prohibits reflective access in a third party library that somehow ended up in your 11's EAR classpath. Play safe from the start, tear the different JDKs apart and check twice carefully.

What I omitted for brevity:

- transitive dependencies/ good style to write poms
- [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to have reproducible builds
- usage of WAR- and EAR-Maven-plugins since they differ dramatically between versions for JDK-6 and -11 on how to setup the classpath
- using [toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) so all developers have a common platform, may spread to build nodes
- recommendations regarding jdeps which is partly broken because of the Maven plugin and partly because of treatment for multi-release jARs (that will show up with JDK 11 dependencies)
- Maven profiles that allow command line switches to alter build behavior
- releasing through Maven introducing funny quirks based on JDK, Maven and your SCM.
- static code analysis, PMD is one of the most flexible that will run in this setup even having the same ruleset for both JDKs while others might not or at least not easily (Coverity, Sonarqube, CAST, …)
- security checks, org.owasp:dependency-check-maven will trigger a lot of warnings in JDK 6 branch, some libraries don't evolve anymore for this target JDK

And normally a parent pom is contains a lot of `dependencyManagement` and `pluginManagement` so all module poms can omit versions and detailed configuration. Your approach goes against this, forcing a JDK 6 branch and a JDK 11 branch through the same parent. It is always forced from parent onto modules and the latter cannot alter or cherry pick.

If there isn't a real trade-off to switch from Ant to Maven, don't do it. Maven requires a lot by contract, esp. when it comes to file system layout vs. artifact content – to build a WAR/ an EAR you either need to follow the rules or have a lot of plugin-configuration.